# Topological shape of the equilibrium point

Tags: topology, chaos-theory, complex-systems

"All dynamical system possess topological shapes that characteristics it's equilibrium point"-so my question is what is the topological shape of the equilibrium point for a cart and Inverted pendulum system?(i.e for both of the equilibrium points the pendent position and the Upright position)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Which equations for the cart-inverted-pendulum system you'd be considering ([those here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pendulum#Equations_of_motion))? And, for completeness, could you add the source of your quotation?

Comment: Hey!, hi there once again-NO! that's not the equation

Comment: So, can you share it with us?

Comment: I mean you should include all the necessary information in the question, you should edit it to add the missing equations and sources.

Comment: k let me try to write it down...

Comment: Maybe it has already been answered here: [Equilibrium points of an inverted pendulum on a cart](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3024483/418568)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90766/discussion-between-akhil-krishnan-and-stafusa).